# Short story where an immortal woman is going to get euthanized

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, immortality

All I remember is the following details from a magazine I read in high school:

- Most likely a short story.
- Mother and son are nigh immortals through life extensions technology.
- They are talking about how after living so long (i think hundreds of years) they are more friends rather than mother and son.
- The mother is planning on committing euthanasia since she is bored with living.
- In the story, there is a limit on child birth, as every new human takes up additional resources.
- Should be a relatively well-known story as it was in a major science type publication.

Comment: when were you in high school? 1945 or 2012? ;) - in other words, good info here on how to ask a good story-id question: https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question

Comment: "Limits on child birth" and "bored immortals wanting to end it" are pretty standard for stories about societies of immortals through life extension technology. Can you remember any *specifics* that might distringuish your story from all those other life extension stories? A character name? Was the story set on earth, in space, on another planet?

Comment: By a "science type publication" do you mean something like *Nature* or *Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences*, or do you mean a popular science magazine like *Discover* or *Scientific American* or *Popular Science*, or do you mean a science FICTION magazine like *Asimov's* or *Analog*? Do you recall the titles of any of the magazines you read in high school?